# What is $\frac{1}{2}$ equal to in $\mathbb{Z_7}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is $\frac{1}{2}$ equal to in $\mathbb{Z_7}$?

I have this system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2a+4b+3c=0 \\ 
2b+d=1 \\ 
a+c+4d=2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

And one solution is $(1,\frac{1}{2},1,0)$ but the solutions must be expressed in $\mathbb{Z_7}$

Comment: $2^{-1} = 4 \pmod 7$.

Comment: As the previous comment says, the inverse of $2$ is $4$ because $2*4=8=1 \mod 7$. Therefore, instead of dividing by $2$, you can just multiply by $4$.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using $\frac12$, from a purely technical standpoint. But it does look somewhat off and depending on your teacher, they might not give you full score for it.

Comment: @Arthur I don't think $\frac{1}{2}$ exists in $\mathbb{Z_7}$

Comment: @sam Sure it does. It is, by definition, the number you multiply by $2$ to get $1$. Such a number doesn't exist in $\Bbb Z$, but it does in $\Bbb Z_7$. Thanks to that you can also use the regular quadratic formula to solve quadratic equations modulo an odd prime (assuming the square root of the discriminant exists, of course).

Comment: @Arthur What do you mean?

Comment: What do I mean by what? The quadratic formula thing? I mean that $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ makes perfect sense and may be used modulo odd primes. Just remember that square roots and fractions behave differently, and you'll be good to go. By the definition of $\frac12$? I mean exactly what I said, that $\frac12$ is, by definition, the unique element such that $2\cdot \frac12 = 1$.

Comment: @Arthur Please explain me in a practical way why $\frac{1}{2}$ is included in $\mathbb{Z_7}$.

Comment: Because, as others have pointed out, $4$ fulfills the defining property of $\frac12$, namely that $2\cdot 4=1$. Thus $\frac12$ exists, and we have $\frac12=4$. I have never said that $0.5$ exists in $\Bbb Z_7$, whatever $0.5$ is supposed to mean in $\Bbb Z_7$.

Comment: It might make things more clear if you write $2^{-1}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$.  @arthur isn't referring to the rational number $\frac{1}{2}$, he's referring to the property that defines it in $\mathbb{Q}$ -- namely, that it is the multiplicative inverse of $2$.

Comment: It is standard practice to use $\frac 12$ to mean the multiplicative inverse of $2$ (***!IF!*** such an inverse exsits).  As $7$ is prime $Z_7\setminus \{0\}$ is a multiplicative group and so it does exist.  So one can say $\frac 12 = 4$.  I'm a bit weary of saying it "exists" and "equals" $4$ in the same sense I'd be weary of saying $32$ is "in" $\mathbb Z_74$ and that $32$ "equals" $4$.  But that's .... moot.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_7$ is not the set of integers $\{0,..., 6\}$.  It is a set of seven classes where $[i] = \{z \in \mathbb Z| z \equiv i \mod 7\}$.  and $[\frac 12] =[i] \in \mathbb Z_7; \forall k\in [i], 2*k \equiv 1 \mod 7$.  As such $[\frac 12\ = [4] = \{....,-17,-10,-3,4,11,18,...\}$ because $[2*4] = \{...-34,-34 + 7, -20,-20+7,-6, -6+7, 8, 8+7, 11, 11+7,...\}= [1]$. This *IS* standard practice.

Comment: Ah, I see! You haven't been taught this yet.  You got $\frac 1n$ by somehow having to solve an equation $2k = 1$.  You can avoid this by replacing the $1$ with $1+7 = 8$ and $2k = 8$ so $k = 4$.  This is an "abuse of notation" as *none* of these things are *equal* to each other; they are *equivalent* to each other.

Comment: Of course, you can't do division unless the divisor and the equivalence mod are co prime.  $4x = 6 \mod 8$ doesn't mean $2x = 3 \mod 8$ (although it does mean $2x \equiv 3 \mod 4$).  However as $7$ is prime this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $2^{-1} \equiv n+1 \pmod{2n+1}$.

But if this is an exercise, you might be expected to write out the steps to the solution using multiplication rather than division.

Comment: "1/2", in any number system, is the number that, when multiplied by 2, gives 1.  So one way to do that is to try every possible product (not that difficult with base 7). 2*0= 0, 2*1= 2, 2*2= 4, 2*3= 6, 2*4= 8= 1 (mod 7), 2*5= 10= 3 (mod 7), 2*6= 18= 4 (mod 7).

Comment: @user247327, I fail to see how that is an improvement over the simple theorem I give in the answer.

Comment: I think user247327 is saying that if one does not know the theorem then trial and error would be a way to do.  We don't actually not what the question is.  But on the other hand you theorem is extremely easy to prove.  SO easy it looks deceptively harder.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of real numbers, $\frac{1}{2}$ is the number such that when you multiply it by $2$, you get $1$. Clearly $1$ and $2$ exist in $\Bbb Z_7$ so the analogue of $\frac{1}{2}$ would be the number $x$ such that $2x = 1$ in $\Bbb Z_7$. That is to say that

$$2x-1 = 7n$$

for some $n$. Checking the elements of $\Bbb Z_7$, we see that

\begin{align}
2\cdot 0 - 1 &= -1 \neq 7n \\
2\cdot 1 - 1 &= 1 \neq 7n \\
2\cdot 2 - 1 &= 3 \neq 7n \\
2\cdot 3 - 1 &= 5 \neq 7n \\
2\cdot 4 - 1 &= 7 = 7\cdot 1 \\
2\cdot 5 - 1 &= 9 \neq 7n \\
2\cdot 6 - 1 &= 11 \neq 7n
\end{align}

Thus the number that you multiply $2$ by to get $1$ is $4$ and so the notion of $\frac{1}{2}$ is $4$ in this setting.

Comment: This is so unusual for me but I understand now

Comment: @sam Part of that is because of how mistakenly real numbers are taught, particularly multiplicative inverses. They're really defined by $xy = 1$, not $y = \frac{1}{x}$ (which may not make sense in every number system like this one). I'm glad I can help!

Comment: Is it a mistake if i write $\frac{1}{2}$ in the solution?

Comment: @sam Partially. Write it as $2^{-1}$ instead which is the more accepted notation and I would note that $2^{-1} \equiv 4$ in this setting.

Comment: The exercise tells me to "express the solutions with non-negative integer numbers less than 7"

Comment: Yes and $4$ is integral, $\frac{1}{2}$ is a fraction, which is not integral - at least in its presentation.

Comment: I'd go further, and say the problem's badly expressed. There are no integers in $\Bbb Z_7$; only equivalence classes of integers.  The problem OP (and others) have with $\frac{1}{2}$ is in part because the "1" and the "2" mean something different in $\Bbb Z_7$ than they do in $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb R$, but they're written exactly the same. Of course, it's easy once you're used to it...but so are most things.

Comment: @JohnHughes very fair follow-up!

Answer (score 0):

"1/2", in any number system, is the number that, when multiplied by 2, gives 1.  So one way to do that is to try every possible product (not that difficult with base 7). 2*0= 0, 2*1= 2, 2*2= 4, 2*3= 6, 2*4= 8= 1 (mod 7) (we could stop here), 2*5= 10= 3 (mod 7), 2*6= 18= 4 (mod 7).  1/2= 4 (mod 7).

We can also argue that 2x= 1 (mod 7) is the same as 2x= 1+ 7y for integers x and y.  We can write that as 2x- 7y= 1.  Now, use the "Euclidean algorithm": 2 divides into 7 three times with remainder 1 so 7(1)- 2(3)= 2(-3)- 7(-1)= 1.  That is, one solution to 2x- 7y= 1 is x= -3, y= -1.  But it is easy to see that x= -3+ 7k, y= -1+ 2k is also a solution for any k: 2(-3+ 7k)- 7(-1+ 2k)= -6+ 14k+ 7- 14k= 7- 6= 1.  Taking k= 1 gives a positive answer, x= -3+ 7= 4, again.  This second method is suited to "modulo" problems with large base.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Z_7$ viewed as a ring system (and because $7$ is prime, as a consequence, a field) is what is called a *complete residue system*.

The elements $0,1,....,6$ are each a *residue class* and the element $k$ represents the class of all integers that are equivalent to $i$ modulo $7$.

Now admittedly the are no integers that are equivalent to $0.5$ modulo $7$ but that is not what the residue class of $\frac 12$ means.

$\frac 12 = 2^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2$.  As $\mathbb Z_7$ is a ring then ***!!!IF!!!*** a multiplicative inverse of the residue class element $2$, that is what we would call $\frac 12$.

*This is legitimate and ACCEPTABLE practice despite seeming* weird.

So... as $2*4 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ we state $\frac 12 \equiv 4 \mod 7$.

And that's it.

===

Going back to the original problem.

You could avoid the issue by using equivalences:

$2a+4b+3c\equiv 0 \mod 7$

$2b+d\equiv 1 \mod 7$

$a+c+4d \equiv 2\mod 7$

... $2b + d \equiv 1 \mod 7 \implies 2b \equiv 1 - d \mod 7$

$\implies 2b \equiv 8 - 8d \mod 7\implies $

$b \equiv 4 - 4d \mod 7$.

Issue avoided.